# Rudin 3.50 use of limsup

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis

Why can't I simply take the limit of $|\gamma_n|<|\beta_0a_n+\dots+\beta_Na_{n-N}|+\epsilon \alpha$ and then also show that since $|\gamma_n|>0$ then $0\leq \lim_{n\to \infty}|\gamma_n|\leq 0$? I am noticing that the use of $\limsup$ must mean that this method is invalid. Why must I use the $\limsup$ method of showing that $\limsup \gamma_n=\liminf \gamma_n=0$ in this case?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Usually when they do that it's because you cannot quite claim that $\lim$ exists at that point of the proof.

Comment: That's a remarkable property of limsup and liminf, they always exist, while the limit does not

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro so I can say if they are equal, then the limit exists and is equal to them?

Comment: @SamKirkiles: this is Example 3.18 (c) in the book that you are reading :-)